# Elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3+X$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $p$ be prime s.t. $p=a^2+4b^2, a\equiv 1\,mod\,4$.

Then, for $f=X^3+X$, $a_E(p)=2a$?

(Here, $a_E(p):=p+1-\#\{(x,y)\in\{0,...p-1\}^2|x^3+x\equiv y^2\,mod\,p\}$)

Comment: What is the context ? The number of points on $y^2=x^3+x\bmod p$ is studied in the theory of elliptic curves with complex multiplication (here by $\Bbb{Z}[i]$)

Comment: Consult [OEIS sequence A138515](https://oeis.org/A138515).

Comment: @reuns - this is an exercise in lecture note for undergraduate number theory course (without hint, not hw) and was skipped in class, so the professor probably tried not to use things like Z[i]. I do not know the original reference..

Comment: @Somos - I see the sequence, but I don't see how they got that sequence. Is there any way to obtain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the direct reference i will cite a related result from [Koblitz, Introduction to elliptic curves and modular forms]. It is a Theorem from II, §2, The zeta function of $E_n$, pages 59, 60, where $E_n$ is the "congruent number problem" elliptic curve:
$$
E_n\ :\ y^2 = x^3-n^2x\ .
$$
The results needed to prove the result in the sequel are using the Gauss and Jacobi sums, defined for a multiplicative character $\chi:\Bbb F_q^\times\to\Bbb C^\times$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(\chi) &= \sum_x\chi(x)\psi(x)\ ,\\
J(\chi_1,\chi_2) &= \sum_x\chi_1(x)\chi_2(1-x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Above $\psi$ is an additive character, the sums are over elements in the field.)

It is related, because the given curve $Y^2=X^3+X$ and the curve $E_2$ of equation $y^2=x^3-4x$ are isogenous. Now let us cite / state:

> Let $E_n$ be the curve $y^2=x^3-n^2x$, considered over the field $\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ elements. Here, the prime $p$ does not divide $2n$. Then
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> Z(E_n/\Bbb F_p, T)
> &=\frac{1-2aT+pT^2}{(1-T)(1-pT)}\\
> &=\frac{(1-\alpha T)(1-\beta T)}{(1-T)(1-pT)}\ ,
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   where $\beta=\bar\alpha$, $a$ is the real part of $\alpha$ (or of $\beta$).
>   Moreover:
>
> - $\alpha,\beta$ are $\pm i\sqrt p$ in case of an odd prime congruent to $3$ modulo four,
> - in the case $p$ is an odd prime congruent to $1$ modulo four, then $\alpha\in\Bbb Z[i]$ is characterized by having the norm $p$, and by being congruent with $\left(\frac np\right)$ modulo $2+2i$.

This is a generalization of the posted result.

The result for $p\equiv 3$ modulo four is simple to obtain, the polynomial $f$ given by $x^3+x$, respectively $x^3-n^2x$ being odd, so we can group points $\ne 0$ in $\Bbb F_p$ in pairs $\{x,-x\}$, and exactly one of $f(x)$, $f(-x)=-f(x)$ is a squaer.

The result for $p\equiv 1$ modulo four and $n=2$ leads to the posted question. (The $2$ is a square, so $\left(\frac2p\right)$ is $=1$.)

---

*Comment*:

Here are some numerical examples, supported by sage code for the first primes:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( QQ, [1, 0] )
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + x over Rational Field
sage: for p in primes(200):
....:     if p%4 != 1:    continue
....:     ap = E.an(p)
....:     a = ZZ(ap/2); b = sqrt(p-a^2)
....:     print "p = %3s :: a_E(p) = %+3s = 2*(%+3d) :: p = %3s = (%+3d)^2 + %2s^2" % (p, ap, a, p, a, b)
....: 
p =   5 :: a_E(p) =   2 = 2*( +1) :: p =   5 = ( +1)^2 +  2^2
p =  13 :: a_E(p) =  -6 = 2*( -3) :: p =  13 = ( -3)^2 +  2^2
p =  17 :: a_E(p) =   2 = 2*( +1) :: p =  17 = ( +1)^2 +  4^2
p =  29 :: a_E(p) =  10 = 2*( +5) :: p =  29 = ( +5)^2 +  2^2
p =  37 :: a_E(p) =   2 = 2*( +1) :: p =  37 = ( +1)^2 +  6^2
p =  41 :: a_E(p) =  10 = 2*( +5) :: p =  41 = ( +5)^2 +  4^2
p =  53 :: a_E(p) = -14 = 2*( -7) :: p =  53 = ( -7)^2 +  2^2
p =  61 :: a_E(p) =  10 = 2*( +5) :: p =  61 = ( +5)^2 +  6^2
p =  73 :: a_E(p) =  -6 = 2*( -3) :: p =  73 = ( -3)^2 +  8^2
p =  89 :: a_E(p) =  10 = 2*( +5) :: p =  89 = ( +5)^2 +  8^2
p =  97 :: a_E(p) =  18 = 2*( +9) :: p =  97 = ( +9)^2 +  4^2
p = 101 :: a_E(p) =   2 = 2*( +1) :: p = 101 = ( +1)^2 + 10^2
p = 109 :: a_E(p) =  -6 = 2*( -3) :: p = 109 = ( -3)^2 + 10^2
p = 113 :: a_E(p) = -14 = 2*( -7) :: p = 113 = ( -7)^2 +  8^2
p = 137 :: a_E(p) = -22 = 2*(-11) :: p = 137 = (-11)^2 +  4^2
p = 149 :: a_E(p) = -14 = 2*( -7) :: p = 149 = ( -7)^2 + 10^2
p = 157 :: a_E(p) = -22 = 2*(-11) :: p = 157 = (-11)^2 +  6^2
p = 173 :: a_E(p) =  26 = 2*(+13) :: p = 173 = (+13)^2 +  2^2
p = 181 :: a_E(p) =  18 = 2*( +9) :: p = 181 = ( +9)^2 + 10^2
p = 193 :: a_E(p) = -14 = 2*( -7) :: p = 193 = ( -7)^2 + 12^2
p = 197 :: a_E(p) =   2 = 2*( +1) :: p = 197 = ( +1)^2 + 14^2
```

These explicit numerical examples are here, hoping that the questions gets more support.